# User friendly paging for report page type?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, pagination, paging, user-experience

I have a report page that currently using a paging like this:

[image]

But my PM is asking me to implement a Google-like paging because he want that the user can interact with the page only by clicking and don't have to use their keyboard to input in the page number. But in my opinions, I don't think Google paging is suitable for a report page which contains many pages/records, and the users will not be able to quickly go to a page that outside the displayed range.

I'm thinking about combine both the paging which means it has the displayed range like Google paging and also a text box to quickly jump to a page but it may look messy right?

So I'm looking for someone that experienced in this to give me some advices.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as your example) you have a report of 30 pages then googlesque paging won't help your users get to (say) page 21 from page 1 but will the users know that they need to go to page 21? If you do need to be able to jump to any given page then replace your markup above to use a drop-down list with auto-postback enabled and drop the Go button; no typing required and any-page navigation :-) Prev & Next might be user friendly too if end-to-end reading is a usual practice.